# Rails: Abstract Classes to apply to models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, abstract-class

Even though, it is a beginner rails question, I wanted to ask on here, stackoverflow, just to get the logic of this right

Basically I'm looking for a solution to create an abstract class (but since we are mentioning about rails, it's more like **abstract models**). The reason why I could not understand it is because I always generate my models and controllers (without scaffold) and I couldn't find any online solution such that I will generate a model that inherits from an abstract class I've predefined.

Basically, assume that I have a class **Creature** with common attributes like eyes, nose etc. and I want to create **Human** and **Dog** class inheriting from that class. How would I be able to do that. Would it be possible to add an option to terminal command `rails g controller Human inherits:Create` or anything like that.

Sincerely, looking for the common and the efficient solution.

Comment: Edit the generated model to extend your base class? Or use a mixin/module, or use STI, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rails generators don't have this functionality, but you always can do it by yourself.

```
# app/models/creature.rb
class Creature
  attr_accessor :eyes, :nose
end

# app/models/human.rb
class Human < Creature
end

# app/models/dog.rb
class Dog < Creature
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your simple and amazing answer! One question question though. When I migrate the db, will the attributes from the abstract class apply to the Human and Dog table?

Comment: No. This classes do not have persistance in db. As you want they are abstract. 8) You should inherit your class from `ActiveRecord::Base` if you want to store it attributes in database. There are many patterns to do it. @DaveNewton said about some of them in his comment.